# Evento FocusLost de Java usando Swing

Tags: java, java-swing, eventos

Quisiera que el mensaje que está programado para que se muestre una vez que el `JTexfield1` pierda el foco, no se muestre si doy un clic fuera de mi aplicación en cualquier parte de mi escritorio. Aquí les pongo el código de ejemplo:

```
private void jTextField1FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hola "+jTextField1.getText());
}
```

Nota: Este no es el código de mi aplicación, sólo puse algo bien simple para que se lleven mejor la idea de lo que necesito.

Comment: Lo unico que se me ocurre es que tengas una variable booleana asociada a un listener que salta cuando sales y entras de la ventana entonces en el metodo que nos has posteado solo tendrías que ver si es true o false con un if y en el caso de ser true que te muestre el Joptionpane nose si esto responde a tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a probar y te confirmo.

Comment: Creo que puedo resolver este problema utilizando los eventos del mouse. Me fue de mucha ayuda tu comentario, Gracias.

Comment: nada, para eso estamos, cuando tengas la solución edita tu pregunta o haz una nueva respuesta para que otro con tu mismo problema pueda solucionarlo tambien

Answer (score 0):

Esto puedes hacerlo añadiendo un `FocusListener` a tu textfield.

Es decir:

```
jtextfield1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hola" + jTextField1.getText());    
    }

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```